# Is there a way to binary search a column of a 2D std::vector without creating a new vector?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, binary-search, stdvector

I am solving [Leetcode 74: Search a 2D Matrix](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix/) in C++20 in which a partially ordered (in row-major) 2D matrix is to be searched for an element.

The solution finds a row in which the target must reside, if at all, and searches in that row.

To do that, it binary-searches on the rows' last elements, looking for the first row with a last element greater equal to the target.

Is there a way to use `std::lower_bound` to search the rightmost column, without creating the rightmost column as a `std::vector`?

[Example]

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

auto searchMatrix(auto&& matrix, auto target) {
  // MAYBE use an iterator?
  auto rightmost_col = [&]{
    using Col = std::remove_reference<decltype(matrix[0])>::type;
    auto rightmost_col = Col();
    for (auto i : std::views::iota(0, std::ssize(matrix))) {
      rightmost_col.push_back(matrix[i].back());
    }
    return rightmost_col;
  }();

  auto find = [&](const auto& space) -> std::optional<decltype(target)> {
    auto pos = std::ranges::lower_bound(space, target);
    if (pos == std::ranges::end(space)) return std::nullopt;
    return pos - std::ranges::begin(space);
  };

  if (auto candidate_row = find(rightmost_col)) {
    if (auto candidate_col = find(matrix[*candidate_row])) {
      return matrix[*candidate_row][*candidate_col] == target;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

auto main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]] char** argv) -> int {
  auto matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{1,3,5,7}, {10,11,16,20}, {23,30,34,60}};
  auto target = 3;
  auto result = searchMatrix(matrix, target);
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << result << std::endl;
}
```

I tried using a `view`, but certain concepts were not satisified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) to create a view consisting of the last element of each `vector`:

```
auto searchMatrix(auto&& matrix, auto target) {
  auto rightmost_col = 
    matrix | std::views::transform([](const auto& inner) -> const auto& {
               return inner.back();
             });
  // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7119vY6bP)

Or you can do a binary search directly on `matrix | std::views::join` (with only one line)

```
auto searchMatrix(auto&& matrix, auto target) {
  return std::ranges::binary_search(matrix | std::views::join, target);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jcEGMzaqT)

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: @argmaxmax You might be interested in another approach.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Second one is a gem

Comment: @MarekR Isn't your answer my answer?

Comment: I've started writing my before your edit :/.

Answer (score 1):

ranges in C++20 rocks (if used properly):

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    bool searchMatrix(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix, int target)
    {
        using namespace std::ranges;
        return binary_search(views::join(matrix), target);
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GhGWaWebh